# How can I make a SQL (Query) that is set as a record source in a form to be called once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Background: working with MS Access as a front end and SQL Server as a back end to organize data of every student found in a school.

Well I've been working on MS Access forms and I've set the record source as a query and set the intended text boxes , combo boxes , etc... to the property that was received.

Now the problem is that the queries for every student is being executed while on the form load or changes from one record to the other. I've come to this conclusion by viewing the SQL profiler and noticed that there is a large amount of queries being executed (It take approx. 14 seconds to load one record).

Is there a way to go around this?

Here is the SQL script that is being used to retrieve the the data (Set as a record source on the form itself).

```
SELECT 
    PERSON.id, PERSON.id_number, 
    Student.Student_Status, PERSON.name, 
    PERSON.surname, PERSON.dob, PERSON.address_1, PERSON.address_2, 
    PERSON.town, PERSON.mobile, PERSON.telephone, PERSON.postcode, 
    PERSON.id, PERSON.nationality, PERSON.dual_nationality, 
    PERSON.gender, Student.student_type, Student.mcast_email, 
    PERSON.euCitizen, PERSON.email, PERSON.NI_no, 
    PERSON.next_of_kin, Student.Form, course.course_name, 
    course.course_code, CourseYear.Year, Institute.Institute_name
FROM 
    ((((PERSON 
LEFT JOIN 
    Student ON PERSON.ID = Student.person)
LEFT JOIN 
    CourseYear ON Student.id = CourseYear.student) 
LEFT JOIN 
    Yearlyprogramme ON CourseYear.course = Yearlyprogramme.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    course ON Yearlyprogramme.course = course.id) 
LEFT JOIN 
    Institute ON course.Institute = Institute.id;
```

These properties that are retrieved are set to the text boxes and and combo boxes to show data. Is there a way to call this query once for each student without having to the a `WHERE` clause on the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, Access queries with multiple LEFT JOINs on linked SQL Server tables often behave very badly.

If you can't avoid the LEFT JOINs, [create a **SQL Server view**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175503.aspx) from your query, link it in Access, and use the linked view as record source of your form.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this out, Is there a reason why LEFT JOINs work badly on Linked SQL Server Tables?